# Boostrap navbar-expand not working properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm working on building a portfolio website currently. This is my first time using bootstrap, so I'm still getting the hang of things. Currently, I'm attempting to build a navbar that expands using navbar-expand, but it's only showing the collapsed version and the button is turning up transparent. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is my HTML

```
<header>
<div class="container-fluid"
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light" style="background-color: #bdd4f9;">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Name Here</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNav" aria-controls="myNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="experience.html">Professional Experience</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="samples.html">Work Samples</a>
      </li>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Replacing `navbar-expand-lg` with `navbar-expand` should keep it always expanded. Use `navbar-expand-sm` to keep it collapsed on small devices.

Comment: @Klooven So will I need two instances of the nav?

Comment: No. You use the class with a specific breakpoint and the nav will expand on any larger screens than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be more specific about what Bootstrap is doing: Bootstrap provides tools to allow the author not only to style html elements but to style them differently at different screen sizes. `.navbar-expand-lg` behaves differently from `.navbar-expand-sm`, for example. If you want the nav menu to always be expanded, use `.navbar-expand` with no -sm, -md, -lg, or -xl appended to the class name.

Bootstrap uses `.navbar-expand-lg` in the example code on its [Navbar documentation page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/), but does explain that

> Navbars require a wrapping .navbar with
>   .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl} for responsive collapsing and color
>   scheme classes.

You may append {-sm|-md|-lg|-xl} depending on when you want your navbar to stop expanding and begin to stack vertically. This is a common pattern in Bootstrap by the way, there are a lot of customizable classes based on mobile responsive breakpoints, so be advised going forward a lot of styling may be tweaked to the degree to which your design is to be responsive.

https://codepen.io/mdlanglais/pen/VxPmyR