# Navbar toggler is always opened and not working properly

Tags: html, css, toggle, navbar

I'm having issues with bootstrap navbar. The toggler is always opened and whenever I click at the icon it won't do anything. I think it has something to do with the javascript files included but not sure. Here is some sample code. Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//storage.googleapis.com/instapage-app-assets/134/031a761e2b05d2bed213fd1f07412755.css" media="screen" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800&subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,greek,greek-ext,latin-ext,vietnamese" rel="stylesheet">

<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-xl navbar-light border-bottom box-shadow py-2">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="logo.png" />
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
          <li class="nav-item active homeNavLink">
            <a href="/home">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/link1">Link1</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/link2">Link2</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/link3">Link3</a></li>
          <li class="nav-item"><a href="/link4">Link4</a></li>
          <li>
            <div type="button" class="btn btn-primary navbar-btn"><a href="/login" class="linkInNav text-white">Sign in</a></div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080394/boostrap-navbar-expand-not-working-properly) might help with part of your issue.

Comment: Remember you put navbar-expand-xl class in navbar it will only collapse in extra large screen.

Comment: @RobMoll That actually solved the use thank you!