# navbar navbar-expand not responsive

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, navbar

I am using the navbar navbar-expand in my program to set up navigation. On the normal computer screen it works fine. The problem is that it doesn't change it width to the actual screensize when I use a smaller screen (Ipad).

GOOD:
[image]

BAD BEHAVIOUR:
[image]

I followed the docs of https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/components/navbar/ to set this up. I didn't use any custom css besides background color to influence this. I tried though, to force the navbar to always take 100% width, but it never does. Found some similar topics, like this one: [Boostrap navbar-expand not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50080394/boostrap-navbar-expand-not-working-properly), but it doesn't answer the question. It in facts state that it should be responsive.

Why is this behaviour occuring on  "navbar navbar-expand" and how can I 'force' to change size according to the screen?

To be complete I also provide here below the html of my header component:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand" style="background-color: #02767c;">
    <div class="container-fluid">

      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><img src="./assets/img/testlogothumbnail.gif">
                  </a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="logout()">Log out</a></li>
                      </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <!--
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          </li>-->

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/overzichtproducten">Overzicht Producten</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/bonnenoverzicht">Overzicht Bonnen</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/addConsignatiebon">Bon toevoegen</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/gebruikersoverzicht">Gebruikers Overzicht</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/addgebruiker">Gebruiker Toevoegen</a>
        </li>
 


          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              Beheren
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          

              <li><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/eigenschappenoverzicht">Eigenschappen</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/merkenoverzicht">Merken</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/matenoverzicht">Maten</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/kleurenoverzicht">Kleuren</a></li>
              <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>

              <li><a class="dropdown-item" routerLink="/export">Exporteren</a></li>

            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/webshopOverzicht">Webshop</a>
        </li>

          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/mailing">Mailing</a>
          </li>
        </ul>


        <div class="flexcontainerbaskets">
          <div style="width:50%">
            <form class="d-flex" role="search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit" (click)="calculateAndPayOut()">
                <div>
                  <fa-icon class="fa-3x" [icon]="faHandHoldingDollar"></fa-icon>
                </div>
                Uitbetalen
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>

          <div style="width:50%">
            <form class="d-flex" role="search">
              <button class="btn btn-outline-dark" type="submit" (click)="calculateAndSell()">
                    <div>
                      <fa-icon class="fa-3x" [icon]="faBasketShopping"></fa-icon>
                    </div>
                    Winkelmand
              </button>
            </form>
          </div>

        </div>



      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the problem is not that your header is not responsive, but your table is not. Html loads from top to bottom. Your header is the first thing that is being loaded. So it takes the width of the screen, as it is instructed.

Later in the page, your html finds a table, which has to be generated by input by your ts file (since you use angular I assume the tabledata is geratedd by "let .. of .."). Your table expands the size of the parent to whatever it needs to show the data. The parent of your table is the body.

If you would insert your table in a another  tag, you would be able to prevent this behaviour from happening. Do:

```
<div class="tableContainer">
//put  the table her
</div>
```

in your css file, do this:

```
.tableContainer{
    overflow: scroll !important;
    width: 100vw !important;
    //--> maybe it also works with width:100% !important.
}
```

This will prevent the page from changing the width of the body after the header is already loaded. It will only make the table scrollable inside the general screen-width.